# performSegueWithIdentifier: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, null, viewcontroller

I wish to allow selecting a certain row whereby, an action outlined as below will occur:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

        // Ensure controller knows which dataset to pull from,
        // so detail view is correct
        var friendChat: Friend!

        friendChat = mappedFriends[indexPath.row]

        // Now set the conditional cases: if a friend then chat, if user then friend request if not user then can invite them:
        if(friendChat.statusSort == 2) {

            var controller : IndividualChatController!

            print(friendChat.name)

            controller.friendChat? = friendChat
            controller.senderId? = Global.sharedInstance.userID
            controller.senderDisplayName? = Global.sharedInstance.userName

            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showIndividualChat",sender: controller)

        } else
            if (friendChat.statusSort == 1) {

            print("Can invite to be friend")

        } else if (friendChat.statusSort == 0) {

            print("Invite to Feast")

        }

}
```

However, during the assignment, of:

```
            controller.friendChat? = friendChat
            controller.senderId? = FeastGlobal.sharedInstance.userID
            controller.senderDisplayName? = FeastGlobal.sharedInstance.userName
```

The error: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` appears.

Why would this occur? How can this be alleviated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring, but not assigning a value to the variable `controller` here:

```
var controller : IndividualChatController!
```

You are making a promise that it is not nil by setting the type to an implicitly unwrapped optional with the exclamation mark, i.e. `IndividualChatController!`

However, that promise is not kept, because no value is assigned to it and it is in fact nil at the time this code runs:

```
controller.friendChat? = friendChat
```

This is why you are getting the fatal error.

The fix would be to assign a value to the `controller` var when you declare it.  For example:

```
var controller:IndividualChatController = IndividualChatController()
```

Comment: Please see question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37581531/passing-data-with-performseguewithidentifier-nil, it accurately displays the resolution

Comment: @Sauron  I see. Perhaps you should delete this question then.  The question you linked to has a different problem, and different code presented in the question.  This question here is asking why you were getting a fatal error, which is what I addressed in my answer.  The question you link to above is asking about passing data through a segue, which has a different, correct answer for that problem.