# passing data with performSegueWithIdentifier nil

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I have the segue setup as:

[image]

and the tableView row selection:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    // Ensure controller knows which dataset to pull from,
    // so detail view is correct
    var friendChat: Friend!
    if searchController.active && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
        friendChat = filterMappedFriends[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        friendChat = mappedFriends[indexPath.row]
    }

    // Now set the conditional cases: if a friend then chat, if user then friend request if not user then can invite them:
    if(friendChat.statusSort == 2) {

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showIndividualChat", sender: friendChat)

    } else if (friendChat.statusSort == 1) {

        print("Can invite to be friend")

    } else if (friendChat.statusSort == 0) {

        print("Invite to Feast")

    }
}
```

and the prepareForSegue:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {

        // Ensure controller knows which dataset to pull from,
        // so detail view is correct
        let friendChat: Friend
        if searchController.active && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
            friendChat = filterMappedFriends[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            friendChat = mappedFriends[indexPath.row]
        }

        // Now set the conditional cases: if a friend then chat, if user then friend request if not user then can invite them:

        if segue.identifier == "showIndividualChat" {

            let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! IndividualChatController
            controller.friendChat = friendChat
            controller.senderId = Global.sharedInstance.userID
            controller.senderDisplayName = Global.sharedInstance.userName
        }
    }
}
```

However, the object `friendChat`, seen in `controller.friendChat`, of the destination controller is always nil.

How can I pass the data:

```
        controller.friendChat = friendChat
        controller.senderId = Global.sharedInstance.userID
        controller.senderDisplayName = Global.sharedInstance.userName
```

to the destination controller successfully?

Comment: The first thing you are doing in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is deselecting the row, so when you try and access the selected row in `prepareForSegue`  you are going to get no row selected.  You are passing the `friendChat` as your sender in `performSegueWithIdentifier` so in `prepareForSegue` you can just say `let friendChat = sender as? Friend`

Comment: Thank you, that worked! If you want to write up an answer

Comment: Sender needs to be a UIView or a UIViewController it should not be used to pass a data object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first thing you are doing in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is deselecting the row, so when you try and access the selected row in `prepareForSegue` you are going to get no row selected.

Since you are passing the `Friend` instance as your `sender` to `performSegueWithIdentifier` you can just say `let friendChat = sender as? Friend` in `prepareForSegue`;

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) 
    if segue.identifier == "showIndividualChat" {
        if let friendChat = sender as? Friend {
            let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! IndividualChatController
            controller.friendChat = friendChat
            controller.senderId = Global.sharedInstance.userID
            controller.senderDisplayName = Global.sharedInstance.userName
        }
    }
}
```

For Swift 3

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) 
    if segue.identifier == "showIndividualChat" {
        if let friendChat = sender as? Friend {
            let controller = segue.destination as! IndividualChatController
            controller.friendChat = friendChat
            controller.senderId = Global.sharedInstance.userID
            controller.senderDisplayName = Global.sharedInstance.userName
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer. (Voted.) Another way to handle this would be to save the selected row (or row and section, if needed) to an instance variable in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and then use that row in preapareForSegue. A third way would be to not deselect the row in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. Then the table view's `indexPathForSelectedRow` would still be valid.